# GameCenter Social.localUser id uniqueness on Unity

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, game-center, game-center-leaderboard

Thanks to click my question.

I'm developing a game on Unity integrated with Google Play Games and Game Center.
Recently, i transferred my app into another developer's account on AppStore.
And it looks like that Social.localUser.id has been differentiated after transferring.
The problem is, i connected Social.localUser.id with account on database.
So when the Social.localUser.id become different, they can't find their own account.
I want to know how Social.localUser.id of Game Center decided.
Do they become different on app transfer?
What should i do to get old Social.localUser.id.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SocialPlatforms.IUserProfile-id.html) states that the `id` comes from [`teamPlayerId`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/gamekit/gkplayer/3174857-teamplayerid).

The documentation for `teamPlayerId` states:

> For the local player, this identifier is the same across all local player instances of your games that use the same developer Team ID.

So, the short answer is that if you transfer your app to a different developer team, you should expect to get different identifiers.  Unfortunately at this point there is nothing you can do, apart from, perhaps, try transferring it back.

If you had created and persisted your own unique identifier on device and on your server then you could match the new identifier to the old, but now it is too late.